# how to use Typescript Components in javaScript React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a React file that I use with JavaScript but in the condition, I need to use some `.tsx` file in my components but when I use .tsx components it gives me an error:

```
Failed to compile
Failed to load parser "@typescript-eslint/parser' declared in 'package.json » eslint-config-react-app#overrides[@]': Cannot find module 'typescript', 
Require stack: 
- C:\remotePackRlab-acab49ee44aa8f06acbfc147116dbc3387885161\node_modules\@typescript-eslint\typescript-estree\dist\parser.js 
- C:\remotePackRlab-acab49ee44aa8f6acbfc147116dbc3387885161\node_modules\@typescript-eslint\typescript-estree\dist\index.js 
- C:\remotePackRlab-acab49ee44aa8f06acbfc147116dbc3387885161\node_modules\@typescript-eslint\parser dist\parser.js 
- C:\remotePackRlab-acab49ee44aa8f06acbfc147116dbc3387885161\node_modules\@typescript-eslint\parser dist\index.js 
- C:\remotePackRlab-acab49ee44aa8f06acbfc147116dbc3387885161\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\lib\config-array-factory.js 
- C:\remotePackRlab-acab49ee44aa8f06acbfc147116dbc3387885161\node_modules\@eslint eslintrc\lib\index.js 
- C:\remotePackRlab-acab49ee44aa8f6acbfc147116dbc3387885161\node_modules\eslint\lib cli-engine\cli-engine.js 
- C:\remotePackRlab-acab49ee44aa8f6acbfc147116dbc3387885161\node_modules\eslint\lib cli-engine\index.js 
- C:\remotePackRlab-acab49ee44aa8f6acbfc147116dbc3387885161\node_modules\eslint\lib\api.js
ab-acab49ee44aa8f06acbfc147116dbc3387885161\node_modules\eslint-webpack-plugin\dist getESLint.js 
- C:\remotePackRlab-acab49ee44aa8f6acbfc147116dbc3387885161\node_modules\eslint-webpack-plugin\dist\linter.js 
- C:\remotePackRlab-acab49ee44aa8f06acbfc147116dbc3387885161\node_modules\eslint-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js 
- C:\remotePackRlab-acab49ee44aa8f6acbfc147116dbc3387885161\node_modules\eslint-webpack-plugin\dist\cjs.js 
- C:\remotePackRlab-acab49ee44aa8f6acbfc147116dbc3387885161\node_modules\react-scripts\config webpack.config.js 
- C:\remotePackRlab-acab49ee44aa8f06acbfc147116dbc3387885161\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.
```

Comment: Does this help - https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/ ?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
npm install -g typescript
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cd C:\remotePackRlab-acab49ee44aa8f06acbfc147116dbc3387885161\
npm install typescript --save
```